# Как отправить стикер в телеграмм боте написанном на Python(Aiogram)

Tags: python, aiogram

Как отправить строку и стикер вместе
Я хочу чтобы бот после команды /start выводил приветствие и в конце любой смайлик.

Comment: так все таки стикер или смайлик?

Comment: @ZxNuClear смайлик

Comment: скопируйте его и вставьте в сообщение 

Answer (score 0):

ID стикера можно получить в этом боте: https://t.me/idstickerbot

```
@dp.message(Command(commands=['start', 'старт']))
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Привет! (просто смайлик вставить)")
    await message.answer_sticker("CAACAgIAAxkBAAEKwCtlU88O1WOkV4Ah4lnYSmJd0R5FuQACIAADwZxgDGWWbaHi0krRMwQ") # id стикера
```

Документация: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/message.html#aiogram.types.message.Message.answer_sticker

Comment: как выяснилось автору нужно просто добавить смайл в тексте

Comment: Да, я уже перечитал)